# Bubble sorting module not working seems; output wrong list (java)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am writing a program that should output an array, the elements of the array reversed, the sum of the array, the average of the array, min and max of array, and the array sorted (ascending by selection sort and descending by bubble sort). Everything seems to check out, BUT the module descendingOrderBBS()'s output is incorrect. This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;


public class Main
{

public static String input;
public static int n;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] file1 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int[] file2 = new int[]{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20};
    int[] file3 = new int[]{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21};

    inputData();

    switch (input)
    {
        case "file1":
        {
            System.out.println("original array: ");
            printArray(file1);

            System.out.println(" ");

            System.out.println("reversed array: ");
            reverseArray(file1);

            System.out.println(" ");

            System.out.println("The sum of all elements: " + sum(file1));

            System.out.printf("The average of all elements: %.1f%n", average(file1));

            max(file1);

            min(file1);

            //System.out.printf("Array in ascending order (Selection Sort): %-10s", ascendingOrderSS(file1));

            ascendingOrderSS(file1);

            System.out.println(" ");

            descendingOrderBBS(file1);

            //System.out.printf("Array in ascending order (Bubble Sort): %-10s", ascendingOrder(file1));

            break;
        }
        case "file2":
        {
            System.out.println(file2);
            break;
        }
        case "file3":
        {
            System.out.println(file3);
            break;
        }
        default :
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("File not found, try again: ");
            inputData();

            break;
        }
    }

}

private static String inputData()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please input file: ");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();

    return input;
}


private static void printArray(int f[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%-10s", f[i]);
    }

}

private static void reverseArray(int f[])
{
    int end = f.length - 1;

    for (int start = 0; start < end; start++, end--)
    {
        int temp = f[start];
        f[start] = f[end];
        f[end] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%-10s", f[i]);
    }

}

private static int sum(int f[])
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
    {
        sum += f[i];
    }

    return sum;
}

private static float average(int f[])
{
    float average = 0;

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
    {
        sum += f[i];
    }

    average = sum / f.length;

    return average;
}

private static void max(int f[])
{
    int largest = f[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
    {
        if (f[i] > largest)
        {
            largest = f[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Max: " + largest);
}

private static void min(int f[])
{
    int smallest = f[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
    {
        if (f[i] < smallest)
        {
            smallest = f[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Min: " + smallest);
}

private static void descendingOrderBBS(int f [])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < f.length; j++)
            if (f[i] < f[j])
            {
                temp = f[i];
                f[i] = f[j];
                f[j] = temp;
            }
    }
    System.out.println("Array in descending order (Bubble Sort): ");

    for (int x = 0; x < f.length; x++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%-10s", f[x]);
    }
}

private static void ascendingOrderSS( int f [])
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int minIndex = 0;

    for (a = 0; a < f.length - 1; a++)
    {
        minIndex = a;

        for (b = a + 1; b < f.length; b++)
        {
            if (f[b] < f[minIndex])
            {
                minIndex = b;
            }
        }

        int temp = f[minIndex];
        f[minIndex] = f[a];
        f[a] = temp;
    }

    System.out.println("Array in ascending order (Selection Sort): ");

    for (int x = 0; x < f.length; x++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%-10s", f[x]);
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the whole program run together

```
Please input file: file1
original array: 
1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9                10         
reversed array: 
10        9         8         7         6         5         4         3         2         1          
The sum of all elements: 55
The average of all elements: 5.0
Max: 10
Min: 1
Array in ascending order (Selection Sort): 
1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         10         
Array in descending order (Bubble Sort): 
2         1         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         10        
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've tried changing the variables to a/b instead of i/j. I made all the modules private to see if that would make a difference, but nothing I've tried has done a thing. Oh and I've also tried using different IDEs.
This is the output with both sorting modules together:

```
 ascendingOrderSS(file1);

 System.out.println(" ");

 descendingOrderBBS(file1);

Array in ascending order (Selection Sort): 
1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         10         
Array in descending order (Bubble Sort): 
2         1         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         10        
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Output with ascending module ignored:

```
//ascendingOrderSS(file1);

System.out.println(" ");

descendingOrderBBS(file1);


Array in descending order (Bubble Sort): 
10        9         8         7         6         5         4         3         2         1         
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm not sure on why descendingOrderBBS() is changing. I've been up till 5:12am finishing this last project.

All fixed:

```
Array in ascending order (Selection Sort): 
1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8            9         10         
Array in descending order (Bubble Sort): 
10        9         8         7         6         5         4         3         2         1         
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `sum / f.length;` is integer division. Make `sum` a `float`.

Comment: Thanks!! Average works perfect now :) Any ideas about the modules ??

Comment: Of course it affects, in your sorting algorithms you are modifying your input array in both of them. Sort over a copy, without changing your original one. And I notice your Bubblesort is clearly wrong and needs to be repaired.

Comment: @RafaelPalomino True although the point of a method that sorts an array is that it sorts it in the correct order no matter what order it was previously in.

Comment: Also I cannot reproduce this issue, only executing `descendingOrderBBS` without executing `ascendingOrderSS` still gives the unwanted result, not the result in the question

Comment: @RafaelPalomino Sounds great, but I'm a bit new to this. Not sure how to make a 'copy' of the array without. Are you saying to set the array to a variable then pass that variable to the module?

Comment: I don't believe your bubble sort algo is correct. Try focusing on that.

Comment: @RafaelPalomino You are half right. The bubble sort has issues, but the 2 functions have no impact on each other. Both sorting functions should work independently.

Comment: @Mark Of course is the idea of sorting, no matter the input, I agree that point. But if the OP is asked to sort the input in different ways (I guess this is the case, because looks like a homework), he needs to work over a copy of the original one and his actual approach would be wrong. It's a subtle difference.

Comment: Yes She** has been rewriting the Bubble sort. I'll inevitably get it eventually. Thanks for ya'lls time always.

Comment: if (f[i] < f[j]) @N.Page you are greater beginning coder.

Answer (score 1):

For your first issue why it's printing `5.0` and not `5.5` is because `sum / f.length` is a division of integers and the value after the `.` will be dropped, however turning `sum` into `float` or casting `sum` to `float` will solve this issue.

Your current code (this prints `1.0`):

```
float average = 3 / 2;
System.out.println(average);
```

The fix (this prints `1.5`):

```
float sum = (float)3 / 2;
System.out.println(sum);
```

`3` and `2` are the variables `sum` and `f.length` in your code.

Comment: Thank you! I knew that part would be an easy fix, but any ideas on the sorting modules??

Comment: @N.Page I cannot reproduce that issue, when I'm only calling `descendingOrderBBS` the output is still `2  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10`

Comment: I'm not sure why, but descendingOrderBBS works fine by itself like how i copy/pasted it, at least for me. It doesn't work for me when it's with ascendingOrder. When its with the other module is when i get this bad result. But apparently everyone thinks the bubble sort has issues, so i must be wrong. I wish i knew what they were lol!!